# Multiplying the values of elements inside an array by 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to make a function that can take either an array or a value, and double it. I tried looking for a way to grab each element in an array, and then multiply it by 2, but I am not getting the needed result when I run the code.

I feel like I am missing something simple here, but searching through stackoverflow and google hasn't helped me resolve this.

Thanks in advance for an advice/help!

```
function double(value) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    value = value.map(function(element) {
      return element * 2;
    });
  }
  return value * 2;
} 

// What the results should be, if it works:

double(2); // 4
double([1, 2, 3]); // [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return value * 2;` will produce `NaN` if `value` is an array.

---

You only want to do the `*` if `value` isn't an array like so:

```js
function double(value) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    value = value.map(function(element) {
      return element * 2;
    });
  } else {
    value *= 2;
  }
  return value;
} 

console.log(double(2)); // 4
console.log(double([1, 2, 3])); // [2, 4, 6]
```

So to sum it up:

1. If we're dealing with an array, `map()` each value to `* 2`
2. Otherwise, just `* 2` the `value`
3. Return `value`

---

I've decided to alter `value` to show the issue, the only difference with [@Munleashed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69661237/5625547) is that he's returning the value right away, we could simplify this even more using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) like so:

```js
if (Array.isArray(value)) {
  return value.map((v) => v * 2);
} else {  
  return value * 2;
}
```

Then, why not go further by using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
function double(value) {
  return (Array.isArray(value)) ? value.map((v) => v * 2) : (value * 2);
} 

console.log(double(2)); // 4
console.log(double([1, 2, 3])); // [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: This really helped, thank you! I guess I thought that since I returned element already, that I didn't need to return value at the end (and that the 'else' was implied/default, if the 'if' statement returned 'false').

Comment: Glad it helped. Please see my latest edit for more details about the other answer, and how we can simplify this even more.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to return the value.

```
function double(value) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return value.map(function(element) {
      return element * 2;
    });
  }
  return value * 2;
}
```